# DragDrop on new Excel Sheet gives "Object reference not set to value"

Tags: c#, devexpress, excel-2007, office-interop, excel-interop

I am using devExpress. Office 2007. c#. When I drag and drop my results in 1/2/3 excel sheet works fine, but dropping results on new sheet gives Object reference not set to an instance of a value. Suggestions ?

Comment: Could you post some code to illustrate the problem?